# Centering inside class CSS

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to center my tiny boxes inside the bright green box.

When I'm not zoomed in:

[image]

When I zoom in, with the magic of Masonry, boxes realign. However, they are not centered in the middle. I would like be able to center these boxes.

Not centered and zoomed in:

[image]

Here is a link to my codepen:

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/Cpedg

However, the centering is perfect in codepen but on my browser, the boxes look like the pictures above. Perhaps google chrome/browser issue? I tried putting `margin: 0 auto;` in different classes of my CSS but none seem to do the trick. =/

Comment: Maybe you should try grids. YUI, Bootstrap, Foundation etc.

Comment: Does bootstrap have the Masonry packing feature? That is the only reason why I chose Masonry because it allows packing

Comment: I was referring to grids. Seems like you wanted that feature. Masonry uses JS, but the responsive frameworks I mentioned provides that with CSS.

Comment: In my experience, css frameworks don't complement js libraries like Masonry at all, as they use absolute positioning calculated by the script.